# How to remove all whitespace from a text file

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to remove all whitespace using Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2019.1.2. I have a simple text file with json data.

I've tried using find and replace with regex enabled, but to no avail.

Comment: What's your text file and regex pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press the CTRL + R to open the replace panel, and enter a whitespace in the first input field, leave the second input field empty.

Then click the replace all button.

[image: remove all whitespace]

If you want remove all whitespace including line break, you can enter \s and enable the regex option.

[image: remove all whitespace including line break]